# React, Redux, Mobx] Qual a melhor forma de gerenciar estado com paginação?

Tags: javascript, react, front-end, redux

Uso o mobx, e agora também hooks, para gerenciar estado da aplicação (se usasse redux enfrentaria o mesmo problema), e não encontrei uma melhor forma de gerenciar listagens com paginação.

Se tenho uma lista no estado global e vários componentes usam, se um componente precisar incrementar a página para mostrar mais resultados, isso fará com que outro componente seja atualizado (não pode acontecer), além disso caso queira extrair dados da listagem (como total de itens, por exemplo), para mostrar em vários componentes (e serem atualizados consequentemente) não consigo, pois a listagem é parcial.

Minha solução foi usar rxjs e gerenciar o estado das listagens no próprio componente (sei que isso não é uma boa prática), e criar services pras apis, neles criei um Subject (do rxjs) e para cada ação do service (salvar, atualizar, ...) emito uma ação. Nos meus componentes inscrevo para ouvir as ações e atualizar o estado dos componentes (fazia mais ou menos isso quando usava Angular).

Se tiverem alguma recomendação de artigo ou vídeo que dê uma luz, agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A melhor forma" é a melhor forma para o seu caso. Você pode salvar na [store](https://redux.js.org/api/store) a página individual que cada componente está "observando" na lista, de maneira que cada componente teria seu acesso individual às páginas. Todos os componentes são "atualizados" quando a store é modificada, isso é inevitável, porém, você tem total controle do que é renderizado ou não. Isto posto, precisa definir muito bem o comportamento que quer. Quando componente X alterar a página da lista, como componente Y deverá se comportar? Se o componente Y não pode ser atualizado, então precisa controlar a página atual em que cada componente se encontra.

Eu uso o Redux para esse tipo de coisa, mas essa é uma escolha pessoal. A sua questão é mais uma questão de semântica, precisa definir bem o comportamento que quer.